# Python Curiosity

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.4

I am curious as to how this program reads. You have the foo functions up top. "Thing" is a global variable. It sets "Thing" which equals 100 to "Item" which also now equals 100. Return "Item" == 0 is what I am not too sure about. "Item" then is equal to 0? Then going down to the flag = False. So "when not flag:" is called, it asks for users input and for whatever reason until you enter "0" the flag turns True and "Thing" now equals 0. If someone can explain how this works I would appreciate it

```
def foo(item):
    global thing
    thing = item
    return item == 0

thing = 100
flag = False
while not flag:
    flag = foo(int(input("Give me what I want here: ")))
print(thing)
```

Comment: `==` is evaluation, not assignment; the function returns whether or not (`True` or `False`) `item` is equal to `100`. The program is terrible, by the way; it seems almost deliberately confusing.

Comment: It is not a real program. I am trying to understand the functionality of how this works.

Comment: Well, `thing` and `Thing` aren't the same thing, `when` and `while` aren't the same thing, so your question is meaningless as-is. You may think jonrsharpe is being nit-picky, but the Python interpreter is a lot more nit-picky than him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` is set to whatever the user responded with when prompted for `Give me what I want here`, converted to an integer. In turn `thing` is set to that value too (`thing = item` binds the global `thing` to whatever `item` points at).

So if the user enters `0`, `item` is set to `0`, then `thing` is set to `0` and `item == 0` returns `True`, ending the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(item): # 3: item is the int(user_input)
    global thing # 4 :means you are modifying the global variabl 'thing'
    thing = item # 5: you set the global variable 'thing' to equal the int(user_input)
    return item == 0 # 6: you evaluate the int(user_input) to 0, if int(user_input) == 0 it will return True, 
    # else return false


thing = 100
flag = False
while not flag: # 1: while not flag(False) which is the same as while True, a infinite loop
    flag = foo(int(input("Give me what I want here: "))) # 2: takes user input, turns it into a int and call foo with 
    # that value
    # 7 : flag is set to the  whatever is returned from foo, either True if the user input is 0, or false, if not.
print(thing) # 8 if the loop ends(if the int(user_input) == 0) you will print the thing, which is 0, set on set 5.
```

---

A good way to see the program flow is to print every line of the program, and maybe some variables, like so:

```
print ("#1")
def foo(item):
    global thing
    thing = item
    print ("#4 thing=%r, flag=%r,item=%r" % (thing, flag,item))
    return item == 0

thing = 100

flag = False
print ("#2 thing=%r, flag=%r"%(thing,flag))
while not flag:
    print ("#3 thing=%r, flag=%r" % (thing, flag))
    flag = foo(int(input("Give me what I want here: ")))
    print ("#5 thing=%r, flag=%r" % (thing, flag))
print ("#6 thing=%r, flag=%r" % (thing, flag))
print(thing)
```

output:

```
#1
#2 thing=100, flag=False
#3 thing=100, flag=False
Give me what I want here: 1
#4 thing=1, flag=False,item=1
#5 thing=1, flag=False
#3 thing=1, flag=False
Give me what I want here: 0
#4 thing=0, flag=False,item=0
#5 thing=0, flag=True
#6 thing=0, flag=True
0
```